# XAML - CollectionViewSource when passed to custom control stops filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, filtering

I have the following `CollectionViewSource` in the main window and a custom control that utilizes that source:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cl1List" Source="{Binding Path=ResAmountMap}" Filter="OnCl1Filter"/>
//....
<control:ResAmounListView ResAmountMap="{Binding Source={StaticResource cl1List}}" />
```

The custom control is using `ListView`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResAmountMap}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Resource" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The thing is that the `ListView` in custom control displays **all elements** from the source, but I expect it  will display filtered ones.
When I used `ListView` directly in the main window (without custom control) then it displayed filtered only items.

Any ideas why filtering stops working when `CollectionViewSource` is passed to custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have (correctly!) not explicitly set the control's DataContext property, the expression

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResAmountMap}"
```

binds directly to the inherited `DataContext`, and hence directly to the source property in the view model (which accidentially has the same name as the control property).

In other words, the ListView in your control does not use the control property at all.

Write the binding like shown below, and in case it is not a UserControl, replace `UserControl` by the actual base class of your control.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ResAmountMap,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```